# What does $\mathrm{Gal}(f) = S_n$ imply about $f$?

Tags: group-theory, polynomials, galois-theory

Let $f$ be an irreducible polynomial with Galois group $\mathrm{Gal}(f) = S_n$.

What can we deduce about the polynomial $f$?

I have seen many things before that address the converse question: When is $\mathrm{Gal}(f) = S_n$?

The answer to this usually talks about some specific cases that imply the Galois group is $S_n$ such as if we use mod $p$ reduction and show there is a transposition and an $(n-1)$-cycle then we have $S_n$, look at discriminant, etc. but I am interested in necessary conditions (atleast over certain fields) for when this is true.

Intuitively I think if the groups is $S_n$, the roots of $f$ must be 'unrelated' and algebraically independent: If we start with base field $K$ and adjoin the roots $\alpha_{i}$

$$K \leq K( \alpha_{1}) \leq ... \leq K( \alpha_{1}, ... ,\alpha_{n})$$

each of the extensions is non trivial.

So OK, we know that our roots must be 'unrelated' enough s.t. $[K( \alpha_{1}, ... ,\alpha_{n}):K] = n!$

But can we say something more? How about over base field $K = \mathbb{Q}$ for instance?

My motivation for this question comes from looking at the polynomials $f_n(t) = t^n + t + 3$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. (It is simple to show this is irreducible by considering moduli of roots for all $n >1$). On calculating the Galois groups for first few $n$ (using mostly brute force mod $p$ reduction for $n>3$), I have $\mathrm{Gal}(f_{n}) = S_n$ which makes me wonder if this is true for all $n$.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the Galois group of $t^n+t+3$ is isomorphic to $S_n$, see [here](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.tmj/1178242731), reference $[4]$ by Uchida for the characteristic zero case. The article gives a good "intuition" on how the polynomials $f$ look like with Galois group $S_n$.